# transferring a double from server to client

Tags: c#

It is based on C# , .net

Server is 64 bit machine and client is 32 bit machine, a double[] array is sent to client. 
In the client a binaryfile is created using this data.

Is there any chance that the doule value will be corrupted, because server is 64 bit and client is 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not if .NET is both sending and receiving.

It also depends on how you are sending and receiving. TCP is stream based which means that everything sent with a single `socket.Send()` might not be received with a single `socket.Receive()`.

Comment: what will be size of the double in both server and client is it 8 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The following article provides an example where the precision is affected by the system you're on (32 bit or 64 bit):

[MSDN - Double Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx)

The extract that provides the example:

> In addition, the result of arithmetic and assignment operations with
>   Double values may differ slightly by platform because of the loss of
>   precision of the Double type. For example, the result of assigning a
>   literal Double value may differ in the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of
>   the .NET Framework. The following example illustrates this difference
>   when the literal value -4.42330604244772E-305 and a variable whose
>   value is -4.42330604244772E-305 are assigned to a Double variable.
>   Note that the result of the Parse(String) method in this case does not
>   suffer from a loss of precision.

You may want to set the target platform of the application on the server to x86. It's my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) this will force the precision to be equivalent to a 32 bit machine, regardless of what you're actually running on.